# Display total number of sales grouped per month

Tags: php, arrays

I posted this question before, someone here helped me get close to the solution but I can't seem to make it work to display the data like I need it to.

I have this array `$sales` which has a structure like below:

```
array(627) (

[0] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 24
    [month] => (string) 4
  )

[1] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 5


[2] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 6

[3] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 2
    [name] => (string) Audi
    [total]=> (string) 16
    [month] => (string) 4
  )

[4] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 2
    [name] => (string) Audi
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 5
```

What it does is it stores sales information for each type of car and for each month. Some of the months don't have sales so they are blank.
What I want to do is to loop through each type of car and display sales like below in an html table:

```
Car      Jan. Feb. Mar. Apr. May. Jun. Jul, Aug. Sept. Oct. Nov. Dec
Tesla    0    0    0    24   18   18   0    0     0    0    0     0
Audi     0    0    0    16   18    0   0    0     0    0    0     0
```

The problem is, The array I have only displays the month numer and the total if there have been sales in that month. In Tesla's case for example there were sales only on month 4, 5, 6 and I am missing 9 more months.

The help I got was:

```
$result = [];
foreach($sales as $sale) {
    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']]))
       $result[$sale['name']] = [];

    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']]))
       $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] = $sale['total'];
    else
       $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] += $sale['total'];
}
```

This is fine, but how do I map each month of the year with this array? How do I display 0 for months without sale?

I hope you can help me with this. Is a bit complicated for me.

Updated:

```
foreach($cars as $car){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$car .'</td>';
            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
            if (isset($new[$i][$car])){
                echo '<td>'.$new[$i][$car] . '</td>';
            }else{
                echo '<td>'."0".'</td>';
            }   
        }      
       echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Can you output the array so that we can copy paste it? `Var_export($sales);` and copy paste that result to us. It's quite daunting to edit every single line of your array.

Comment: Can't you even comment or anything to my answer?

Comment: @Andreas I am really sorry, thank you very much for this solution, it's quite simple and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that will first build a new array with month as first key, then a new subarray with the car as key and the value as the sales.

I then grab all cars with array_column and sort out duplicates with array_unique.

I then loop the months (1->12) and output with date() the month.
Then I loop the cars and output the values (sales).

```
foreach($sales as $sale){
    $new[$sale["month"]][$sale["name"]] = $sale["total"];
}

$cars = array_unique(array_column($sales, "name", "id"));
$cars[] = "Sum"; // add a car named "Sum" for later use of displaying the sum
//Var_dump($cars);
echo "<table>\n<th>Car</th>";

for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    echo "<th>" . date("M", strtotime("2017-$i-01")) . "</th>"; // create header
    foreach($cars as $car){ // loop through the cars and add zero values to months if there is no sales on each car.
        if(!isset($new[$i][$car])){
            $new[$i][$car] = 0; // add months with 0 values
        }
    }
    $new[$i]["Sum"] = array_sum($new[$i]); // sum the month sales and add it to car "Sum"
}
ksort($new); // sort it on keys (months);

//output each car in a table (including "Sum") using array_column and implode
foreach($cars as $key => $car){
    If($car != "Sum"){
        echo "\n<tr><td><a href='$key'>$car</a></td><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_column($new, $car)). "</td></tr>";
    }Else{
        echo "\n<tr><td>$car</td><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_column($new, $car)). "</td></tr>"; 
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

For php test:
https://3v4l.org/tZNOK
To see what the actual output is:
https://jsfiddle.net/gfjdcj4r/

Edit, added array_sum.
Edit; added html table
Edit; added id as anchor by using the third option of array_column.
This makes the key of $cars the id.
This is then outputed as the anchor.

Comment: This is quite a clean solution, could you please help me with printing the total per month?

Comment: Because I use first key as month I can use array_sum to sum the month total easily. @MegMeg

Comment: this is great, I like this solution, thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry to bother :), Iit's still good, but could you help me to print it vertically, rather than horizontally? It should be each car name and then sales per month, like in the table I display?

Comment: I figured out how to display it in a horizontal table, the sum also works fine, but I need to display it as a single row in the table, but right now it''s inside the loop, so if i try to print the sum a new row is going to be created for each tye of car..

Comment: I updated my question to what i did to display the sales per month horizontally, could you help me on displaying the sum aswell, as a single row?

Comment: @MegMeg That requires a html table. Reworked the code to fit a table. Code is more or less the same. Only difference is that I now loop all months and create "zero values" in the array. I then output it with implode and array_column to grab the correct values.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly :)
If it's not abusing, I noticed I need to have also the Id of the car in the $car array, could you help me that?

Comment: How is that supposed to be used?

Comment: There will be a hyperlink to the car name, which should contain the car id so I can query some of the details about that car.

Comment: @MegMeg see update. Added an anchor to the id of each car. This has to be edited by you slightly. See if it's correct.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, and hypothetically, If I need to add a new field to the table, another unique_Id which is unique for car type, just like the Id, how should I proceed? Should I open another question for this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But yes I think I have gone far enough with this question. Given the time I have spent on this for "only 15 points"

Comment: I'm fine with helping you, but I just don't understand where and how this new field is supposed fit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622130/get-a-subset-of-an-array-and-then-get-only-unique-rows
Here, I explained it here, I changed a bit the fields just for an example. Together with this Id in the hyperlink, I will need also the unique_id of the car..

Comment: I fixed it :D. thank you for your support so far! I wish I could give you more points!

Comment: Alright, I looked at your question but didn't have time to answer. You can upvote answers when you have reached 15 points in rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping an array of length 12 initialized to 0. If the month of corresponding index has a value then change it, else display the intialized value itself

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good, could you please help me a bit with the syntax?

Answer (score -1):

iterate your $result array and for every "car", iterate from 1 to 12 and for every month check if it's exists in the "car" result inner array

```
$result = [];
foreach($sales as $sale) {
    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']]))
        $result[$sale['name']] = [];

    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']]))
        $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] = $sale['total'];
    else
        $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] += $sale['total'];
}

$totalSales = array();
foreach ($result AS $car=>$monthSales) {
    print $car;
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
        if(array_key_exists($i, $monthSales)) {
            print $monthSales[$i]; // put here the names
        }
        else {
            print "0";
        }

        if(array_key_exists($i, $totalSales)) {
            $totalSales[$i] = 0;
        }
        $totalSales[$i] += (isset($monthSales[$i])) ? $monthSales[$i] : 0;
    }
}

for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
   if(array_key_exists($i, $totalSales)) {
       print $totalSales[$i]; // put here the names
   }
   else {
       print "0";
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me printing the total sals for each month? for all cars?

Comment: I added more code... sum while first foreach of printing... and then after iterate again for al months and print the sum

Comment: Have you seen the number of notices there are on your code? https://3v4l.org/GALkX

Comment: see the change in the post... just needed to adding check if $monthSales[$i] isset ot print 0 instead...